# What will the cursor's value be if a SQL query returns no data?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

```
Cursor cursor = this.db.rawQuery("select topic_id from " + TABLE_NAME + 
                   " where Ref_Topic_Id = '"+ ref_topic_id.toString() + "'", null);
```

What will the value of `cursor` be if the above `WHERE` clause doesn't return any data?

Comment: `cursor.getCount()` will be equal to zero `cursor = null`

Answer (score 3):

if you run cursor.getCount() you will get 0

Comment: If cursor is null then how can you perform cursor.getCount() it may be nullpointerexception